# TextFormField in flutter pops the page instead of dismissing the keyboard on backbutton

Tags: flutter, navigation, textformfield

So in my flutter code i have a custom text form field and whenever i try to press back button to dismiss the page it pops that page.

I noticed it only appears if theres a previous page to pop to
if not it simply close the keyboard

I tried setting a will pop scope but didn't work

Comment: can u show us your pop function at back button?

Comment: And a code block with will pop scope please

Comment: What do you mean by back button? A Flutter widget or the device back button/gesture?